# Error Handling / Throw error in Strapi 4.0

Tags: strapi

in Strapi 4.0, i want to validate the input before saving. So i created **lifecycles.js** file as per the documentation and added the code:

```
module.exports = {
    beforeCreate(event) {
         //validation login here;
         if (!valid) {
             throw strapi.errors.badRequest('Invalid Entry');
        }
    },
}
```

How ever `throw strapi.errors.badRequest('Invalid Entry');` is giving an error :

```
Cannot read property 'badRequest' of undefined
```

My guess is the Strapi v4 changed it from version 3. I looked everywhere but couldn't find a solution.

Any idea on how to handle error in `lifecycles.js`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar situation with a forbidden error. I got to do it importing a class from `@strapi/utils/lib/errors.js`

```js
const { ForbiddenError } = require("@strapi/utils").errors;

...

if (!authorized) {
  throw new ForbiddenError(errorMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can show the list of errors based on your requirement

```
const { ValidationError } = require("@strapi/utils").errors;
...
if (formValidationError) {
    throw new ForbiddenError("Fill the form");
}
```

Strapi comes with a lot of error response functions here are they

```
  HttpError,
  ApplicationError,
  ValidationError,
  YupValidationError,
  PaginationError,
  NotFoundError,
  ForbiddenError,
  PayloadTooLargeError,
  UnauthorizedError,
  PolicyError,
```